# How to count total no of lines from .ts files

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have app folder and under that number of modules and components. I need to count only .ts files lines of code. So is there any plugin for VS Code or any other way please suggest?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the command-line tool CLOC (Count Lines of Code).

Installation :

```sh
npm install -g cloc
```

Usage :

```sh
cloc my/app/folder --include-lang=TypeScript
```

You will get an output looking like this :

```
      88 text files.
      88 unique files.
      32 files ignored.

github.com/AlDanial/cloc v 1.82  T=0.12 s (516.3 files/s, 19421.4 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeScript                      60            276            101           1880
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                            60            276            101           1880
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[More info](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc)

Comment: tried your command in cmd (`cloc my/app/folder --include-lang=TypeScript`) but its shown 'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Please refer as [this link](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) for more info

Answer (score 3):

On Unix you can use `wc` to count the number of lines of documents.

```sh
wc -l **/*.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install this package : [sloc](https://github.com/flosse/sloc)

To install :

```
npm i -g sloc
```

Otherwise, if you are using vscode, you can install line-counter plugins

Answer (score 0):

[sloc](https://github.com/flosse/sloc) is even better

`sloc -d --format cli-table --keys total,source,comment app/`

results in

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────┬──────────┬────────┬─────────┐
│ Path                                  │ Physical │ Source │ Comment │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ app/entry.client.tsx                  │ 4        │ 3      │ 0       │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ app/entry.server.tsx                  │ 48       │ 40     │ 0       │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ app/root.tsx                          │ 32       │ 30     │ 0       │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ app/routes/dep.tsx                    │ 18       │ 16     │ 1       │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ app/routes/index.tsx                  │ 5        │ 4      │ 0       │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ app/utils/encryption.server.ts        │ 51       │ 39     │ 3       │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ app/models/cache.server.ts            │ 28       │ 20     │ 3       │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ app/models/depkatalog.server.ts       │ 171      │ 130    │ 19      │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ app/routes/dep/$dep.$avd.$seksjon.tsx │ 64       │ 56     │ 3       │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ app/routes/dep/$dep.$avd.tsx          │ 41       │ 37     │ 0       │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ app/routes/dep/index.tsx              │ 27       │ 25     │ 0       │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ app/routes/dep/$dep.tsx               │ 53       │ 48     │ 2       │
└───────────────────────────────────────┴──────────┴────────┴─────────┘
```